# Can I use .writelines() for writing a single line to a file?

Tags: python, string, file, line

From the doc on [`file.writelines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines):

> Write a sequence of strings to the file. The sequence can be any
>   iterable object producing strings, typically a list of strings.

However, writing single lines also works:

```
>>> with open("/tmp/test", "w") as f:
...     f.writelines("test\n")
... 
>>> with open("/tmp/test") as f:
...     f.readlines()
... 
['test\n']
```

So I'm wondering if `.writelines()` can accept single strings as well as sequences of strings. Any links to python 3 documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm affraid that it iterates over string, thus appending it char after char

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because strings in Python are iterable:

```
>>>> for char in 'test':
....     print(char)
....
t
e
s
t
```

So, this code treats your string as iterable, and appends to the file char after char. It might be less efficent than using `.write()`.